# Property 'pipe' does not work with `zip` operator?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a  code which currently works with the Observable patching mechanism :

```
  Observable
      .zip(..., Observable.timer(0, intervalMS), (x, y) => x)
      .skipWhile(f => f === undefined || f == 0)
      .first()
      .subscribe(...)
```

AsI I've said it uses these imports :

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/zip';
...
```

But now on my way to apply `"rxjs": "~5.5.6"` , it seems that the `zip`  operator doesn't have the `pipe` function :

[image]

> Error:(14, 130) TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type
>   'UnaryFunction, Observable<{}>>'.

I was hoping that I could do :

```
zip(..., timer(...), (x, y) => x).pipe(skipWhile(...),first())
```

**Question:**

How can I fix my code so that I would be able to do :

```
zip(...).pipe(...) ?
```

Because according to the original code , `zip` had a `skipWhile` attached to it.

Comment: The problem is probably somewhere else because this works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-4csnai?file=index.ts

Comment: @martin [Really strange](https://i.imgur.com/wVaKKbi.jpg)

Comment: Wait, you're importing `zip` operator. You have to use `import { zip } from 'rxjs/observable/zip';` if you want to use it as a source Observable.

Comment: omg you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `zip` as a source Observable you have to import it like this:

```
import { zip } from 'rxjs/observable/zip'
```

Answer (score 2):

In RxJS 6.3.3 I had to import from the root of the package:

```
import { zip } from 'rxjs';
```